# Need to do CPU bound processing using 2+ processes in Python by reading from a gzipped file

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a gzipped file spanning (compressed 10GB, uncompressed 100GB) and which has some reports separated by demarcations and I have to parse it.
The parsing and processing the data is taking long time and hence is a CPU bound problem (not an IO bound problem). So I am planning to split the work into multiple processes using `multiprocessing` module. The problem is I am unable to send/share data to child processes efficiently. I am using `subprocess.Popen` to stream in the uncompressed data in parent process.

```
process = subprocess.Popen('gunzip --keep --stdout big-file.gz',
                           shell=True, 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am thinking of using a Lock() to read/parse one report in child-process-1 and then release the lock, and switch to child-process-2 to read/parse next report and then switch back to child-process-1 to read/parse next report). When I share the `process.stdout` as args with the child processes, I get a pickling error.

I have tried to create `multiprocessing.Queue()` and `multiprocessing.Pipe()` to send data to child processes, but this is way too slow (in fact it is way slower than doing it in single thread ie serially).

Any thoughts/examples about sending data to child processes efficiently will help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something simple instead? Have each worker process run its own instance of `gunzip`, with no interprocess communication at all.  Worker 1 can process the first report and just skip over the second. The opposite for worker 2. Each worker skips every other report. Then an obvious generalization to `N` workers.

### Or not ...

I think you'll need to be more specific about what you tried, and perhaps give more info about your problem (like: how many records are there? how big are they?).

Here's a program ("genints.py") that prints a bunch of random ints, one per line, broken into groups via "xxxxx\n" separator lines:

```
from random import randrange, seed

seed(42)
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(randrange(1, 1000)):
        print(randrange(100))
    print("xxxxx")
```

Because it forces the seed, it generates the same stuff every time.  Now a program to process those groups, both in parallel and serially, via the most obvious way I first thought of.  `crunch()` takes time quadratic in the number of ints in a group, so it's quite CPU-bound. The output from one run, using (as shown) 3 worker processes for the parallel part:

```
parallel result: 10,901,000,334 0:00:35.559782
serial   result: 10,901,000,334 0:01:38.719993
```

So the parallelized run took about one-third the time.  In what *relevant* way(s) does that differ from your problem?  Certainly, a full run of "genints.py" produces less than 2 million bytes of output, so that's *a* major difference - but it's impossible to guess from here whether it's a *relevant* difference.  Perahps, e.g., your problem is only very mildly CPU-bound?  It's obvious from output here that the overheads of passing chunks of stdout to worker processes are all but insignificant in this program.

In short, you probably need to give people - as I just did for you - a complete program they can run that reproduces your problem.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

NWORKERS = 3
DELIM = "xxxxx\n"

def runjob():
    import subprocess
    # 'py' is just a shell script on my box that
    # invokes the desired version of Python -
    # which happened to be 3.8.5 for this run.
    p = subprocess.Popen("py genints.py",
                         shell=True,
                         text=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return p.stdout

# Return list of lines up to (but not including) next DELIM,
# or EOF. If the file is already exhausted, return None.
def getrecord(f):
    result = []
    foundone = False
    for line in f:
        foundone = True
        if line == DELIM:
            break
        result.append(line)
    return result if foundone else None

def crunch(rec):
    total = 0
    for a in rec:
       for b in rec:
          total += abs(int(a) - int(b))
    return total
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import datetime
    now = datetime.datetime.now

    s = now()
    total = 0
    f = runjob()
    with mp.Pool(NWORKERS) as pool:
        for i in pool.imap_unordered(crunch,
                                     iter((lambda: getrecord(f)), None)):
            total += i
    f.close()
    print(f"parallel result: {total:,}", now() - s)

    s = now()
    # try the same thing serially
    total = 0
    f = runjob()
    while True:
        rec = getrecord(f)
        if rec is None:
            break
        total += crunch(rec)
    f.close()
    print(f"serial   result: {total:,}", now() - s)
```